# Android app switch between two servers when one down

Tags: android, web-services, rest

We have an application which is very critical and we do not afford downtime. We have an server and have implemented multiple servers architecture at that site when one will be down traffic will be re routed to other server.

But if whole site is down or because of any disaster site is down, I want we can change IP in android APP automatically without deploying new APK. Can we do it?

Comment: Implement FCM silent notification, and add new URL in data. When you receive a notification on the device it should update the existing URL with new one.

Comment: And you can map the server IP with DNS then you don't require to change the IP on the device because you can again map DNS with new IP address on the server down.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't have the two ips within the application, and whenever the first one timeouts, you switch to the second one?

By the way, which client do you use to make request to the API? I like [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) very much.

Comment: One more thing, why you don't configure a server cluster? You could give docker a try.

Answer (score 0):

If the request to the first server goes in timeout, you can simply handle that by repeating the same request at the second server you have got for backup

Answer (score 0):

Following scenario will help you,
**Scenario #1: Check server status using Status Service**

```
if(serverOneIsLive()){
  //do operations through server one
} else if(serverTwoIsLive()){
    //do operations through server two
}

//Write one service to check server is up or down
private boolean serverOneIsLive(){
   boolean status = APICallToServer;
   return status
}
```

**Scenario #2: Firebase Remote Config**
https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/